# Is there any way to find out if selenium is running using code?

Tags: selenium

I want to find out if selenium is running and if it isn't then call a bat file to start it.  Is it possible to find out if selenium standalone is running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, you can invoke the server programmatically -

```
RemoteControlConfiguration settings = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
        File f = new File("C:\\selenium-profile");
        settings.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(f);
        settings.setReuseBrowserSessions(true);
        SeleniumServer seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer(settings);
        seleniumserver.boot();
        setUp("http://www.google.com", "*firefox");
```